# How to make Intellisense workable on SQL Server Synonyms

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server Management Studio 18.12.1 and noticed that I can not use Intellisene on synonyms. Is there a solution available?

I thought this issue was solved? The SQL query is executed without errors, intellisense has been refreshed but it is not working.

[image]

Comment: does the query produce an error with the synonym?

Comment: Does this answer your question:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/configure-intellisense-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Ineffable21 no it does not

Comment: @nbk no error on execution